# Learning C# .net Framework

Tags: c#, .net

I want to learn “C#” and “.net frame work” properly.

I read basic concept of C# language. Since I know C++ It did not took too much time to read C# simple tutorial.

Now when I searched the .net tutorial, most of the sites give C# language feature and some of the .net controls API and class usage.

But I don’t want that. I want basic such as how event loop work, how frame work is designed and some core concepts. For example when I searched the memory handling in .net I got garbage collection in .net, I read it and liked it a lot because it explains how and when garbage collection is going to take place.

One more thing is how read/understand a frame work?

Please help me to understand C#.net frame work properly.

Comment: As I understand it, you are more interested in learning how the .NET framework works than how to apply it, correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287927/best-way-to-learn-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which C# 4.0 Book would you purchase, and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181729/which-c-4-0-book-would-you-purchase-and-why)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Buy the book: CLR via C#, by Jeffrey Richter

Comment: Or any book from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181729/which-c-4-0-book-would-you-purchase-and-why

Comment: reading this book is a requirement for .net developers in our company

Answer (score 4):

I make a habit of reading someone else's code for at least 30 minutes a day. Code rarely comes with explanations fit for beginners, but it sure helps to get an understanding of practical usage of the language.

When looking for a text-book-style language guide, the MCTS self-help books have been more than adequate for my needs. They hardly cover practical usage of the language, but are fairly thorough in the whys and wherefores.

Here's a link to the MS MCTS training site, where you can explore certification exams and find supporting literature. I hope it helps.

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/mcts.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your replay, please can you refer me some source to start with.

Comment: For beginners, take a look at CodeProject.com. A lot of folks like you and me will post small working examples of this or that, which are great for learning the ins and outs of .NET. As you get more comfortable, get the source code for an Open Source project that interests you. The first large(r) project I read was dasBlog.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two completely separate GUI frameworks contained in .NET. The older one is called *Windows Forms* or *WinForms* and is largely a wrapper around the low-level Windows API and Windows native controls. The other one is called *Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)* and is a very new and very different approach.

**How the event loop works:** The event loop is normally referred to as the *message loop*. There is a separate implementation of it in Windows Presentation Forms (WPF), about which I could find no information (sorry). But the WinForms one is actually the same as you would use in a low-level Windows API application. There is a Wikipedia article on the [Message loop in Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows).

**How the framework is designed:** This is a very vague question and is not possible to be answered as such. If you have specific questions about the design criteria or the design process, you can post a new and specific question about it.

Answer (score -2):

you dont have to stack in books, first off find a Reflector program and try to understand codes

Comment: Huh? What does a reflector program have to do with understanding codes?

Comment: well u can read jeffrey book but in practice it wont work, use reflector look the system class and methods how they are written why they are written, up to what? in framework and CLR there is too much myth and also in msdn sometimes author can say sorry we said that but infact this is not!