# What is better when using constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, constructor, coding-style

Ill start with an example or two. Take the following sample class:

```
class Sample
{
    private object _someObject;

    public Sample(object someobject)
    {
        _someObject = someobject;

        // If I then wanted to pass someobject to a method within the constructor, 
        // is it better to use the field version or the parameter version. Example:

        SomeMethod(someobject);

        // OR

        SomeMethod(_someObject);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have just finished the book titled "Efficient C#" by Bill Wagner and would like to know if there are any more books out there with a similar format as this one.

I am interested in knowing why I should write code the way it is written (More efficient IL for example)

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: I'd use the local field, because in a multithread environment, `someobject` could have changed inbetween.

Comment: About the second part of your question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181729/which-c-sharp-4-0-book-would-you-purchase-and-why

Comment: @Corak: surely your comment is argument for using the *parameter* rather than the local field?

Comment: Uhm... the more I think about it; both `someobject` and `_someobject` should not be able to be changed inside the constructor. Or am I missing some very weird race condition where one thread can access a field of an object that is not finished with its constructor? But yes, `someobject` definately can not change inbetween.

Comment: Usually you use underscore in names of private members exactly to avoid typing "this." before. But this is about readability, not performance.

Comment: @Corak: it depends what the method does: `SomeMethod` could be something very long-running.  It can't be advised, but it's certainly possible!

Comment: @ElDog I learnt all I know through self study. using the _ was something I saw whilst reading through someone else's code and liked it. I did not undertand or know that there was an actual reason to use such notation.

Comment: @DanPuzey `SomeMethod` would be a validation routine of some description. As you say, nothing lengthy, just in a method for re-usability.

Comment: @DanielDaranas thank you for the recommendatons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no difference, they're all references to the same object.

Comment: Not necessarily - as @Corak points out in his comment, one is thread safe and one is not.

Comment: @DanPuzey: They are references, if someobject is changed, then _someoject is changed too. Equally unsafe. Still, I usually use the internal field, just for consistence.

Comment: @ElDog: THe point is that if a different thread sets `_someObject = new object()` then this will affect only the field; the parameter will not be changed.  The field is not thread safe; the parameter is.

Comment: If you have to worry about thread safety of instance fields inside a constructor, you have probably done something very wrong.

Comment: @Jamiec For some reason i completely forgot. Also it would not matter for Value Types either if I recall correctly.

Comment: @DanPuzey surely the parameter is only holding a reference to the same object that was passed to it?